# Problema ao carregar o Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Bom dia!

Tenho o seguinte código para carregar o mapa no meu aplicativo:

```
if (mMap == null){
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if(null == mMap)
    {
        SupportMapFragment fragment = SupportMapFragment.class.cast(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        fragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Aparente, os testes funcionaram corretamente, não houve erro ao carregar, mas estou recebendo várias falhas no **play.google**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.b' on a null object reference
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.et.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:395)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
```

O `NullPointerException` ocorre pois, ao tentar adiconar o marker no mapa, e o mesmo se encontra nulo.

Tratei o problema para que não ocorra o `NullPointerException`, mas gostaria de saber o porque o mapa não é carregado?

Pelo que percebi, ocorrem em todas as versões do Android (da 4.0 até 5.1), não é nada específico de uma versão.

Existem outras formas para carregar o mapa?

Desde já agradeço !

Saudações

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é bacana você usar o getLastLocation para ele recuperar o valor da sua posição, verifica tambem se o gps está habilitado e por via de duvida, cria um obj LatLng com o valor "0,0", provalvemente ele está tentando criar o marker no onCreate da Activity, isso faz com que ele pegue o objeto nulo antes de conseguir obter uma localização válida, qualquer coisa da uma olhada no link ([Getting the Last Location - Android](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html))